# Problemas con inserción a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, insert, crud

AL intentar insertar una imagen ami base de datos me sale el siguiente error.

Falló la inserción de la tabla: (1062) Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

El codigo de la inserción es el siguiente:

```html
        public function insertarImagen($identificacionP,$nombreimagen,$descripcionimagen,$imagen){
            if ($this->error==false) {
                $this->conexion->set_charset("utf8");
                $insert_sql="INSERT INTO imagen (idPoreI, nombrei, descripcioni, imageni) VALUES (".$identificacionP.", '".$nombreimagen."', '".$descripcionimagen."', '".$imagen."')";
                //echo $insert_sql;
                if (!$this->conexion->query($insert_sql)) {
                echo "Falló la insercaion de la tabla: (" .$this->conexion->errno . ") " . $this->conexion->error;
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            
        }else{
            return false;
            }
        }
```

El modelo quedo asi

```html
<?php require '../partials/header.php';?>
<?php
    include"../control/dbimagen.php";
    $imagenpublicacion=new dbI();
    $imagen= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
    $error=$imagenpublicacion->insertarImagen($_POST["idPoreI"],$_POST["nombrei"],$_POST["descripcioni"],$imagen);
?>
```

y la vista es la siguiente:

```html
<form action="modelo/insertarImagen.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="usuario">Portafolio:</label>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="codE" name="idPoreI" require="true">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nombre">Nombre de la imagen:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreE" name="nombrei" require="true">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nombre2">Descripcion de la imagen:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre2E" name="descripcioni" require="false"> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="foto">Sube tu foto:</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="imagen" REQUIRED/></br></br>
                                        </div>  
                                        <br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registrar" name="insert">
                                    </form>
```

Comment: veo que declaras la columna `idPoreI` te pregunto esta es llave primaria? es decir la declaraste como `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla en la base de datos? Sin verla, me podría arriesgar a decirte que te ha faltado poner un auto_increment para que el id de la tabla crezca automáticamente. Pero sería mejor que añadieras más información a la pregunta. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Y no relacionado con la pregunta en sí, pero importante: tu código presenta problemas graves de seguridad, es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público.